How to solve "Object literal may only specify known properties"?
I am working on an application with Next.js and faced this problem. I could not understand why this happening. I searched for solutions from stackoverflow and chatgpt but could not solve this.
Code:
export async function getQuestions(params: GetQuestionsParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const { searchQuery, filter, page = 1, pageSize = 10 } = params;

    // Calculate the number of posts to skip based on the page number and page size
    const skipAmount = (page - 1) * pageSize;

    const query: FilterQuery<typeof Question> = {};

    if (searchQuery) {
      const escapedSearchQuery = searchQuery.replace(
        /[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,
        "\\$&"
      );
      query.$or = [
        { title: { $regex: new RegExp(escapedSearchQuery, "i") } },
        { content: { $regex: new RegExp(escapedSearchQuery, "i") } },
      ];
    }

    let sortOptions = {};

    switch (filter) {
      case "newest":
        sortOptions = { createdAt: -1 };
        break;
      case "frequent":
        sortOptions = { views: -1 };
        break;
      case "unanswered":
        query.answers = { $size: 0 };
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    const questions = await Question.find(query)
      .populate({ path: "tags", model: Tag })
      .populate({ path: "author", model: User })
      .skip(skipAmount)
      .limit(pageSize)
      .sort(sortOptions);

    const totalQuestions = await Question.countDocuments(query);

    const isNext = totalQuestions > skipAmount + questions.length;

    return { questions, isNext };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

Errors:

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type 'FilterQuery<Model<any, {}, {}, {}, any, any>>'.ts(2353) (property) title: {     $regex: RegExp; }

Property 'answers' does not exist on type 'FilterQuery<Model<any, {}, {}, {}, any, any>>'.ts(2339) any


Question model:
import { Schema, models, model, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IQuestion extends Document {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  tags: Schema.Types.ObjectId[];
  views: number;
  upvotes: Schema.Types.ObjectId[];
  downvotes: Schema.Types.ObjectId[];
  author: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  answers: Schema.Types.ObjectId[];
  createdAt: Date;
}

const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  tags: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tag" }],
  views: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  upvotes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  downvotes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  answers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Answer" }],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

const Question = models.Question || model("Question", QuestionSchema);

export default Question;


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing. That means you should remove anything unnecessary for the demonstration of the error (it should be minimal) and provide anything necessary, like definitions of any important private/third-party types/values (it should be reproducible). Right now it looks neither minimal nor reproducible so it's hard to proceed. Also, if your question depends on next.js and mongoose you should tag it as such; if not, the [mre] shouldn't involve them.

This error occurs because TypeScript is not aware of the structure of your Question model when used in the FilterQuery. You need to explicitly define the type of query to ensure TypeScript recognizes the correct fields in the Question model.
